# Xcode how to change which viewController loads first at start-up

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am using storyboards, xcode 4.6.1. I have created an app, but now I want to go back and add a new view controller to the beginning. How do I assign this view controller to be the first one to load up at run-time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Choose your viewcontroller in storyboard , click `show the attributes inspector`

and choose `initial scene: is initial view controller`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Initial View Controller**

Initial View controller allows you to initiate storyboard without `Storyboard ID`

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: String(describing: SomeViewController.self), bundle: nil)
let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
```

Xcode 10.3

```
Storyboard -> View Controller

Show Inspectors -> Show the Attributes inspector -> Is Initial View Controller
```

It will update the Initial view controller in the same `.storyboard`.

[image]