# Opening view controller from app delegate using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am trying to create a push notification which determines which view to open according to information obtained from the push.

I have managed to get the information from the push, but I am now struggling to get the view to open

Looking at other stack overflow questions I have the following currently:

App Delegate Did finish loading:

```
     //Extract the notification data
    if let notificationPayload = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary {
        // Get which page to open
        let viewload = notificationPayload["view"] as? NSString
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        //Load correct view
        if viewload == "circles" {

            var viewController = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Circles") as! UIViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = viewController

                        }
    }
```

Currently this is failing on the var ViewController = self... line.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36158926/1223728) answer

Comment: I tried this and it works as far as opening "Circles" view controller. But let say "Circles" view controller is itself within a sub tree of navigation tree of my app. How do I make sure that once I open my app in "Circles" view controller, all the back navigations work? Right now, it opens "Circles" view controller without showing the back navigation.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You have to set ViewController StoryBoardId property as below image.

[image]

open viewController using coding as below in swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

         let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
         let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Circles") as UIViewController
         self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
         self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
         self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

         return true
    }
```

**For iOS 13+** (based on [an article by dev2qa](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-set-application-root-view-controller-programmatically-in-xcode-11/))
Open `SceneDelegate.swift` and add following

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    // If this scene's self.window is nil then set a new UIWindow object to it.
    self.window = self.window ?? UIWindow()

    // Set this scene's window's background color.
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    // Create a ViewController object and set it as the scene's window's root view controller.
    self.window!.rootViewController = ViewController()

    // Make this scene's window be visible.
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    guard scene is UIWindowScene else { return }
}
```

There is an open-source [navigation utility](https://github.com/hovermind/ios-wiki/blob/master/docs/util/navigation-util.md) which attempts to make this easier. [Example](https://github.com/hovermind/ios-wiki/blob/master/docs/navigation.md#launching-first-view-depending-on-condition)

Comment: But this is creating a new instance of the controller.  I want the controller that already has state. Or am I missing something?

Comment: app delegate method is not called when receive a User Notification , why?

Comment: Same for swift vertion but only syntax change.

Comment: but viewDidLoad is not worked in that viewController ("circles")

Comment: latest: put the answer code in `SceneDelegate.scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) ` (FYI, i created a [navigation util](https://github.com/hovermind/ios-wiki/blob/master/docs/util/navigation-util.md) based on [this](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-set-application-root-view-controller-programmatically-in-xcode-11/))

Answer (score 56):

Swift 3:

This is my preferred approach when presenting a new viewController from the current viewController through the AppDelegate.  This way you don't have to completely tear down your view hierarchy when handling a push notification or universal link

```
if let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someController") as? SomeController {
    if let window = self.window, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
        var currentController = rootViewController
        while let presentedController = currentController.presentedViewController {
            currentController = presentedController
        }
        currentController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best approach, You can dismiss this view as well

self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @Imtee: dismiss the presented viewController you mean?

Comment: @LohithKorupolu, if u  want to move from present view controller.

Comment: This worked for me, well done! I put this in the `applicationWillEnterForeground` method of my appDelegate to force restart my app at the splash screen when being reopened (that way, I can properly refresh my data and UI by maintaining a simple 'all through one path' model lol :) Thanks!

Comment: Perfect, Thank you.

Comment: I used the accepted answer previously and ran into problems managing the view hierarchy, and this was exactly what we needed!

Comment: @Imtee didn't dismiss in my case .. can you help?

Comment: let controller = AppStoryboard.FriendsGroups.viewController(viewControllerClass: RTCVideoViewController.self)
        controller.isCallReceived = true
        controller.notification = notification
        if let window = self.window, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
            var currentController = rootViewController
            while let presentedController = currentController.presentedViewController {
                currentController = presentedController
            }
          currentController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

Comment: @KrutikaSonawala , Use self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) hope that work

Comment: Best solution!!

Answer (score 14):

Swift 3

To present the view together with the navigation controller:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"InboxViewController") as! InboxViewController
let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController)

   if let window = self.window, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
       var currentController = rootViewController
       while let presentedController = currentController.presentedViewController {
           currentController = presentedController
        }
           currentController.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Comment: this works...but if you have a tabBar, the tabBar is not show.

Answer (score 8):

First Initialize the `window`

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

For setting `rootViewController` inside `AppDelegate` Class

```
let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Circles") as UIViewController
self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 6):

## There is a swift 4 version

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Circles") as UIViewController
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

return true}
```

Answer (score 5):

**In Swift 3**

```
        let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: StorybordName, bundle: nil)
        let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifierName) as UIViewController
        if let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
        {
            navigationController.pushViewController(initialViewControlleripad, animated: animation)
        }
        else
        {
            print("Navigation Controller not Found")
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd say creating UIWindow each time you want to change rootViewController is bad idea. After couple changes of rootVC (using upper solution) you are gonna have many UIWindows in your app at one time.

In my opinion better solution is:

1. Get new rootVC: `let rootVC = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newRootVCIdentifier") as UIViewController`
2. Set frame for new rootVC from UIScreen's bounds: `rootVC.view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds`
3. Set new root controller for current window (here with animation): `UIView.transitionWithView(self.window!, duration: 0.5, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                    self.window!.rootViewController = rootVC
               }, completion: nil)`

Done!

You don't need method `window?.makeKeyAndVisible()`, cause this solution works on current app window.

Comment: how to dismiss this vc?

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 SWRevealViewController

```
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: navigationcontroller becomes nil if i open the app from extenstion using this code .. do you have any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LandVC") as! LandingPageVC

    destinationViewController.webpageURL = NotificationAdvertisement._htmlpackagePath
    destinationViewController.adID = NotificationAdvertisement._adID
    destinationViewController.toneID = NotificationAdvertisement.toneID

    let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UIViewController

    navigationController.showDetailViewController(destinationViewController, sender: Any?.self)
```

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 4**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LandVC") as! LandingPageVC

    destinationViewController.webpageURL = NotificationAdvertisement._htmlpackagePath
    destinationViewController.adID = NotificationAdvertisement._adID
    destinationViewController.toneID = NotificationAdvertisement.toneID

    let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UIViewController

    navigationController.showDetailViewController(destinationViewController, sender: Any?.self)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

    let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
    let rootNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.window?.rootViewController = rootNC
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```