# accessing UIwebview from appdelegate swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a UIVivewController which inherits UIWebViewDelegate. When I receive at push notification and handle that notification on the Appdelegate. How do I access the webview object to change location of the page.

```
 class WebViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

     let url = NSURL(string: "WEBURL")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)

        webView.delegate = self
    }
```

appdelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
webview.Load(userinfo["link"]) //I need to accesss the webview object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use:

`let vc = self.window.rootViewController as {UIViewController}`

Another idea is that you retrieve your already instantiated view controller as a function variable, set / get your property and set is as the presenting view controller.

See this stack overflow post: [Opening view controller from app delegate using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592521/opening-view-controller-from-app-delegate-using-swift)