# rootViewController isn't working (nil?) on the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwindow

I'm trying to set an object of `myViewController` called `myVC` to the window's rootViewController on the `AppDelegate` like that:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
{
    self.myVC=(myViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
}
```

It's all working when the app is running but on the background it doesn't working at all.

Anybody knows how can I make it work on the background as well?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your rootViewController navigationController or viewController ?

Comment: @Pushpa viewController

Comment: Is the methods get executed, try log something inside the method.

Comment: Look at this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592521/opening-view-controller-from-app-delegate-using-swift

Comment: @BharatModi its get executed when the app is running, how can I know if it's being executed on the background?

Comment: @Pushpa I'll try it, thanks

Comment: Try logging some text with NSLog.

Comment: @BharatModi How can I see the logs when the app is running on the background?

Comment: The app still pushes log statements to the console if your app is running in the background. If your app is not running but is suspended, there is nothing to log anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**EDIT:**

**AppDelegate.m**

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"STORYBOARD_NAME" bundle:nil];
ViewController *ViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER"];[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];     
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:ViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground");
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ADD_YOURCONTROLLER];

[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to present myVC using storyboard and I don't have a navigationController

Comment: Try my EDIT and let me know

Comment: should I use the navigationController although I don't have a navigationController?

Comment: I'll try it when I'll get home and I'll let you know. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105525/discussion-between-kamlesh-shingarakhiya-and-fs-o).

Comment: Okay so in `applicationDidEnterBackground` method put this
`[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:ViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];`

Comment: Use application.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? ViewController