# Swift 3 present view from appdelget when application was off

Tags: swift, ios10, appdelegate, presentviewcontroller

when the user opening the push notification i present view from appdelget by this code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0; // Clear badge when app is launched
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "PushOFF") == false
    {
        registerForRemoteNotification()
    }
    else
    {
        UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    return true
}
func registerForRemoteNotification()
{
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
    {
        let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil{
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    var token = ""
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
    }
    print("DEVICE TOKEN = \(token)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error)
{
    print("Registration failed! error=\(error)")
}
//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    print("foreground User Info = ",notification.request.content.userInfo)
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    print("foreground app",notification.request.content.userInfo)
}

//Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
{

    completionHandler()
    let result = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    print("action User Info = ",result)

    let app = result["aps"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    let title = app["alert"] as! String
    let id = result["id"]?.integerValue
    print("alert=",title,"id=",id!)
    if id != 0
    {
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "login")
        {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(title, forKey: "notificationTitle")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(id, forKey: "notificationId")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            if let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostVC") as? UINavigationController
            {
                    var currentController = window?.rootViewController
                    while let presentedController = currentController?.presentedViewController
                    {
                        currentController = presentedController
                    }
                    currentController?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if the application is working the code run perfect but when the application is off it present "PostVC" view first and present the root-view on top of "PostVC" view!! so you can't see the "PostVC" view.

what is wrong ? but i wouldn't to use `window?.makeKeyAndVisible()`

Comment: What method Is used to show "PostVC" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening view controller from app delegate using swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592521/opening-view-controller-from-app-delegate-using-swift)

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk in the first line in the code 
'  if let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostVC") as? UINavigationController '

Comment: @Mannopson i wouldn't to use 'window?.makeKeyAndVisible()' because I wouldn't to have many UIWindows in my app at one time.

Comment: @bero You shouldn't create a new window. Change your rootViewController

Comment: @Mannopson How ? can you help me please ?

Comment: Are you checked my first comment? This is exactly what you need for this case

Comment: @Mannopson 
the first answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592521/opening-view-controller-from-app-delegate-using-swift by Kirit Modi : The app will create a new window! 
second answer by iDhaval the same solution
Third answer by Quy Bui the same problem with my code when the app off it present "PostVC" view first and present the rootview on top of "PostVC" view!what solution is right ?

Comment: Yes! It's works

Comment: @bero Are you tested?

Comment: @Mannopson too times and it's didn't work :(

Comment: @bero What did you tried?

Comment: @Mannopson i edited the code in the question.

Comment: Looks like you're tried to open a specific view controller from the delegate method of UserNotifications framework. Right?

Comment: @Mannopson right and it's working fine when the app is running and the user touch the notification but when the app is closed and the user touch the notification the app will open the specific view after that will open the initial view on top so the user will see the initial view only!!

Comment: You can open your desired view controller from didFinishLaunching method.

Comment: @Mannopson Okay, what will happen when the application is running and the user will get push notification ? i think nothing will happen when the user touch the notification !

Comment: Of course! If you've not implemented the delegate method. You can do something like that by handling the notification action. I think the default action identifier helpful for you.

Comment: @Mannopson Can you tell me how ? because i'm new :( ,Thank you so much for your helps.

Comment: @bero Ok, but not now! Remember: If you want to open a specific view controller whenever notification is pushed? Do not open the modally presented view controller, always open the child view controller instead.

Comment: @Mannopson Okay take your time and Thanks again for your helps. You are awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I give you an idea. Whenever the notification is fired and the user taps the notification, `UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier` will be called. Try this:

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    switch response.actionIdentifier {

    case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            openViewController()
        })

    default:
        break
    }

    completionHandler()
}
```

This is going to be your function:

```
func openViewController() {
    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostVC") as? UINavigationController
    self.window?.rootViewController = controller
    self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

But as I suggested above open a `childViewController` instead.

```
 func openViewController() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourRootViewControllerIdentifier") as! UINavigationController
    let childViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourChildViewControllerIdentifier") as! YourCustomChildViewController

    rootViewController.pushViewController(childViewController, animated: true)

    self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

I have not tested yet. Let me know if it's works! Good luck

Comment: i used this function
`func openViewController() {
    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostVC") as? UINavigationController
    self.window?.rootViewController = controller
    self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}`
but it's open another UIWindow so i have 2 UIWindow  and the same problem when the app is closed so i can see the initial view only again, But i replaced this function by

Comment: `func openViewController()
    {
        if let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostVC") as? UINavigationController {
            if let window = self.window, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
                var currentController = rootViewController
                while let presentedController = currentController.presentedViewController {
                    currentController = presentedController
                }
       currentController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
}`

Comment: Now it's working perfect finally :D so i don't know how to thank you for your helps . Thank you so much.

Comment: @bero Therefore I recommended open a child view controller