# Opening Safari when launching from background state not possible?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-safari, appdelegate

I was wondering if it is possible to launch safari directly after opening an App through a push notification, so I implemented the following in my `didReceiveRemoteNotification`:

```
if (UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active) {
// This works
UIApplication.shared.open(someurl , options: [ : ], completionHandler: nil)

} else if (UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive) {
//Nothing happens
UIApplication.shared.open(someurl , options: [ : ], completionHandler: nil)

} else if (UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background) {
//Nothing happens
UIApplication.shared.open(someurl , options: [ : ], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

I can put print statements or anything else in the `.inactive` or `.background` states which do get called, so the methods do get called. However the last 2 states are not opening Safari, nothing happens.

Question: Is this intended, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes you can open the Safari View Controller from your remote notification.

Comment: @Mannopson Okay ... then why does above approach not work?

Comment: You have checked states of the app and not anything else.

Comment: @Mannopson I thought the command within those checks does open Safari. It sure does for the first state.

Comment: What you tried? Can you show me your code

Comment: well it is essentially what is shown here. `someurl` gets set above that.

Comment: Have you tried to handle the notification itself ? You can open the Safari from your notification

Comment: @Mannopson What are you suggesting? Maybe you can point me in the right direction. I though I am handling the notification.

Comment: You'll need to implement the UserNotificationDelegate protocol methods.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42616737/6680583