# iOS - Setting 'rootViewController' results in black screen on device only

Tags: ios, swift

With a very basic single view application, I've deleted the main storyboard file and removed any references to it. As such I'm setting the window rootViewController programmatically. However, while this displays the single view (containing a label) correctly in simulator, it displays a black screen when running it on device. Here is the only code for the app.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = DummyViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

I've removed the entry for Main storyboard from the info.plist file, as well as the 'Main Interface' entry in the General settings.

I'm using Swift 3 and targeting an iOS 8 device. I'm using XCode 8.3.1.

There is no output in the console, and there are no exceptions. The viewDidLoad function is even triggering on breakpoint, so the codepath seems to be running correctly.

Any ideas?

Here's the bare bones code for DummyViewController upon request.

```
class DummyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

General settings showing no reference to Main Interface
[image]

Here is the image for the .xib linked to DummyViewController
[image]

** The solution to get around this case is to manually specify the .xib to load for the DummyViewController **

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592521/opening-view-controller-from-app-delegate-using-swift Follow this link

Comment: Please add the code for `DummyViewController` as well

Comment: Thank you for the updated post with the image and code!

Comment: do you use storyboard or xib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the ViewController is not set to display anything. Unless you are using a xib (in which case you would need to load the view controller in a different way, see below), there is nothing describing how the ViewController's view should render.

To test this out, you can add the line `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red` to the ViewController's `viewDidLoad()` method, then run it again on the device- if the background color turns red, then hooray! The next step will be programmatically adding a UILabel.

---

*Loading UIViewController From a XIB*

`let vc = MyViewController(nibName: "xibname", bundle: nil)`

Alternatively, you can mask the loading by adding a custom init inside `MyViewController`:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    required init() {
        super.init(nibName: "xibname", bundle: nil)
    }
}
```

(Thank you [zonily-jame](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928180/zonily-jame) for the addition of hiding it in the class)

Comment: @mbradber Have you deleted the reference to the main interface in the General settings?

Comment: @mbradber It doesn't look like your ViewController is set to display anything, so a black screen would be expected.. please see my updated answer. Does the background turn red?

Comment: So that did work, I see a red background. However, I have a DummyViewController.xib with a label and blue background that is not being rendered on device, as if the original .xib is just being ignored. On simulator the .xib loads and displays correctly.

Comment: Ah okay, so you are using a xib. It looks like what is happening is the xib is not being linked to the ViewController when you render on the device (but it is in the simulator- weird). You could try Clean to try and get the same behavior on both devices.

Comment: Also try to delete your derived data sometimes it messes up your ide

Comment: @Carter Yea, the File's Owner of the Xib is correctly set to DummyViewController, but the Xib is just not being picked up when running on device. I've tried cleaning the project and re-installing app. I'll try loading the DummyViewController and manually loading the .xib. Thanks for your suggestions :)

Comment: @Carter Manually specifying the .xib to load makes it work on both device and simulator correctly. Thanks again.

Comment: @mbradber Glad we were able to figure it out :)
@ZonilyJame Thanks for the edit, I like the idea of abstracting it in the `UIViewController`

Comment: Shorter code and would generate less user-syntax errors produced by **incorrect xib names** if he reuses that kind of init for xib `UIViewController`s. Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

         let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
         let loginView : BaseClassVC = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BaseClassVC") as BaseClassVC
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginView)

         self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
         self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
         self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

         return true
    }
```

Comment: This causes an exception because there is no main bundle as I've removed it from the project. Preferably I wouldn't need to keep this file since I won't be using it.

Answer (score 1):

change Your window root as and set color

```
let viewController:DummyViewController = DummyViewController()
self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
```

**And change your controller**

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialize viewcontroller object and implement white background color to its instance.

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    //Add below 2 lines
    let vc = DummyViewController()
    vc.view.backgroundColor = .white

    window?.rootViewController = vc
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```