# Receiving error: Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier'

Tags: ios, swift

I use the following in my AppDelegate to pop an alert to user when push is received:

```
let topWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
topWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
topWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "message", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
let yesButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    print("you pressed Yes, please button")
    topWindow.isHidden = true
    topWindow.rootViewController?.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier("consumerProfile")
})
let noButton = UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    print("you pressed No, thanks button")
    topWindow.isHidden = true
})
alert.addAction(yesButton)
alert.addAction(noButton)

topWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
topWindow.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
```

My problem is in:

```
topWindow.rootViewController?.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier("consumerProfile")
```

The function `openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier` only exists in views based on a specific `UIViewController` class named `BaseViewController` so i get the following error:

> Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier'

Comment: what is your problem? You are not able to present Alert from AppDelegate or the error that you have posted?

Comment: You just set your `rootViewController` to an empty `UIViewController`. How do you expect to be able to call a method of your custom `BaseViewController` on this `UIViewController`?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592521/opening-view-controller-from-app-delegate-using-swift

Answer (score 0):

Just put your custom class as rootViewController

```
let topWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let topViewController = BaseViewController()
topWindow.rootViewController = topViewController
topWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "message", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
let yesButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    print("you pressed Yes, please button")
    topWindow.isHidden = true
    topViewController.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier("consumerProfile")
})
let noButton = UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    print("you pressed No, thanks button")
    topWindow.isHidden = true
})
alert.addAction(yesButton)
alert.addAction(noButton)

topWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
topWindow.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
```

**UPDATE**

Because your ViewController doesn't have `init()` try this code:

```
let topWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) // Name of storyboard should be same as your
let topViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as? BaseViewController // be sure that `identifier` of BaseViewController is same as in storyboard 
topWindow.rootViewController = topViewController
topWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "message", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
let yesButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    print("you pressed Yes, please button")
    topWindow.isHidden = true
    topViewController.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier("consumerProfile")
})
let noButton = UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    print("you pressed No, thanks button")
    topWindow.isHidden = true
})
alert.addAction(yesButton)
alert.addAction(noButton)

topWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
topWindow.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
```

**UPDATE 2**

There is your `identifier` = `storyboard ID`

[image]

Comment: How does this change the `rootViewController`?

Comment: @maddy Forgot to change topWindow.rootViewController = topViewController

Comment: @YerkebulanAbildin  can't  instantiateViewController, need to use the openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier method if i want the menu structure. When I tried the code on top the app crashed with "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: It's becouse you didn't implement init() and your BaseViewController didn't load all @IBOutlets from storyboard. Try code which I provide to you on bottom of answer

Comment: @YerkebulanAbildin Hi. tried to implement the update but baseViewController has no identifier. Its not connected to a specific UIView but to a slider menu

Comment: identifier you should put inside your storyboard for your viewController

Comment: @YerkebulanAbildin i use identifiers. Each view has a different identifier but none of the views have this class as Custom Class and Storyboard id. Instead each UIViewController that needs access the the functionality of baseViewController is declared thus: class ContactViewController: BaseViewController  but with its own custom class and Identity

Comment: @YerkebulanAbildin my app is based on AKSwiftSlideMenu https://github.com/ashishkakkad8/AKSwiftSlideMenu

Comment: @JohnyDGood ok, I got it. What is your initial Viewcontroller superclass? And what is class of you initial Viewcontroller