# Open Navigation Controller from App Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, appdelegate

I've implemented an URL scheme for the redirect back to my app after payment. When a webpage direct back to my app, the app should open a navigation controller **over** the current view. (So open it modal).

How to do this from the AppDelete in the `func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool`-method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening view controller from app delegate using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592521/opening-view-controller-from-app-delegate-using-swift)

Comment: @the4kman Hi, the differents is that I want to open it OVER my current view.

Comment: what's the version you're targeting? is it higher than iOS 9?

Comment: @MassimilianoDelMaestro Yep! iOS 10+

Comment: @RickdeJong then be careful, whatever method you use to present your view modally, the method "application(_ application:open:sourceApplication:annotation:) -> Bool" its deprecated as of iOS 9. Use the newer "application(_:open:options:)" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the view controller that submitted the request is the one that should display the modal, I'd suggest a different approach. I would suggest defining a notification in the notification center that you use to notify the current view controller.

In your view controller, make a call to one of the Notification center methods like `addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:)` to observe your notification.

Then call a `Notification` method like `post(name:object:)` from your app delegate's implementation of `application(_:open:options:)` when you get the expected URL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a storyboard or you manually create the window in the delegate? If you have access to the window, you can do this:

```
window?.rootViewController?.present(yourViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Otherwise, it should work in all cases:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(yourViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Hi there! I'm using storyboards. Is it possible to do this with a modal transition?

Comment: It is a modal transition. You can customise it by doing `yourViewController. modalTransitionStyle` or customise the `yourViewController. modalPresentationStyle`