# Navigation controller turns to view controller when root view is set to different view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I have a root view that shows up when I first start my app. The root view has a button that when pressed opens another view controller that should have a nav bar at the top with an (add) navigation item. The problem is when I set the root view as the root view in app delegate, my other controller (that opens from a button) fails to show the nav bar with the nav item.

Heres what I mean:

When App Delegate is set to

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.



    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let firstviewController = FirstViewController()
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstviewController)
    let core = CoreViewController()
    window?.rootViewController = navController

    return true
}
```

The navigation controls and navbar all show up but the CoreViewController (the view with the button) fails to show up first as the root controller.

How can first view controller keep its NavControls while have CoreViewController launch first as the root screen?

View Controller with Button

[image]

When View Controller is a Nav Controller

[image]

Comment: you have to do the same thing what you do here in appdelegate to show the first view controller from where you want to show the view controller.

Comment: are you using storyboards

Comment: So set it as something other than the rootViewController?

Comment: I am not using storyboards

Comment: what is this line for let core = CoreViewController()

Comment: It is unused in the example but when I replace the navController with core it makes the view controller with the button show up first.

Comment: I want core to show up first but still navController be a UINavigationController

Comment: try this on button click if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {                                
    window.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CoreViewController()) }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42942702/4552939 check this out

Comment: Manish I pasted your code  into the button click and now get an error  "Variable used within its own initial value"