# HomeViewController not loading after Firebase Google SignIN in AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uikit, ios13

I have successfully configured google sign in my iOS App using Firebase.
After a successful login, I need to make the UIViewController move to HomeViewController.
The AppDelegate class has "didSignInFor" method in which I have added  the following code

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
               let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC")
               self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
               self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

HomeVC is a storyboard id of HomeViewController and restoration id is also same.
But still, it doesn't take me to HomeViewController.
I have referred this stack overflow posts.

[Opening view controller from app delegate using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592521/opening-view-controller-from-app-delegate-using-swift)

Please tell me where I am going wrong. I have referred this video for building the app.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20Qlho0G3YQ

Here's my AppDelegate.swift file https://pastebin.com/WfzhYAKH

Comment: Is the app crashing? I need a little more information of what happens after you successfully login to diagnose the issue.

Comment: please post AppDelegate file ... check if window is nil ?

Comment: try optional binding on window to check if its nil

Comment: @RickySanchez No App doesn't crash. I can get the data of the user. Here's the AppDelegate file  https://pastebin.com/WfzhYAKH

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC")
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

This works for me.

Please comment if you have any questions. Happy to Help!

Comment: I have the same code in my AppDelegate file. But it doesn't work. Some doubts I have: 1 DO we need to use navigation controller for the root controller to move to Home controller?

Comment: I have added this 1 line "self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)" ..... And no we don't need a navigation controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213985/discussion-between-mohit-kumar-and-gunesh-shanbhag).