# How to load all view controllers storyboard, but skip the natural sequence and go direct to a specific view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Suppose I have three view controllers inside a storyboard, I want to load all of them into view controllers stack, but I want to choose which one will appear first to the user. As shown below I would like to show the third view on load, instead to show the first, any glue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1. Using storyboards, you see the arrow pointing to your ViewController 1. Drag that to View Controller 2 or 3.

Option 2. On load of your first view controller, you can [instantiate whichever view you'd like in your `viewDidLoad()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24036067/4008175), provided you have given each storyboard view an ID.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourVCIdentifier")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Option 3. [In your AppDelegate file, you can do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26757245/4008175)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourVCIdentifier")

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```