# Application tried to present modal view controller on itself

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
if userSignedInGlobal == "success"{
    if let mainTabController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabController") as?  MainTabController{
        mainTabController.present(mainTabController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is .'

I need to navigate to a page after Authenticating application with firebase to do so I use the above code after validating the authentication. How do I fix this an reference link or code explaining how to get there would suffice.

Comment: `mainTabController.present(mainTabController, ...`. Your error is right here. You're attempting to have `mainTabController` present itself.

Comment: Thanks @KyleH now I get the error Cannot convert value of type 'MainTabController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'.

Comment: @MRDR in this case you probably have the M capitalized, which means you'd be handing the class type over as an argument, when what you want is an instance of the class handed over as the argument.

Comment: @TomQDRS Attempt to present <Cake.MainTabController: 0x7fba608aca00> on <Cake.MainTabController: 0x7fba6081a600> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: What class is this code written in by the way? From where are you calling it? If you are inside a View Controller, please take a look at @Carpsen90's answer, he tells you correctly what you'd need to change.

Comment: Sorry @TomQDRS I'm on AppDelegate , applicationWillEnterForeground method. Ok will do. Thank you !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are in a UIViewController, then change this line:

```
self.present(mainTabController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you are in the Appdelegate then set your ViewController as the root view controller of the `window` property:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
if userSignedInGlobal == "success"{
    if let mainTabController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabController") as?  MainTabController{
        window?.rootViewController = mainTabController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I'm on the AppDelegate file anything I can do there ?

Comment: @MRDR The AppDelegate isn't it's own View Controller, so it can't "present" a view controller. If you want to programmatically instantiate your Controller from the delegate, please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26757245/4442731

Comment: @Carpsen90 Just figure it myself too. Thank you both for the support much appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

Remove the **controller before** present, so instead of

```
mainTabController.present(mainTabController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

use just:

```
present(mainTabController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```