# Why doesn’t 'self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainPage, animated: true)' work?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a basic app that lets users sign up and login and they will be directed to the main page which has horizontal scrolling and paging enabled. The main view has 3 views which you can swipe left or right to go to the other pages. Here is the code where I set the root view controller.
NOTE: Only if the user has logged in this view controller will be displayed.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let homeScreen = MainScreen()
        let navBar = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeScreen)
        window?.rootViewController = navBar
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


        return true
    }
}
```

I want to display the main page once the user logs in, but the main page doesn't get displayed. Here is the code when the user taps on the login button, I've only given the necessary code:

```
// User found and verified, go to main page
let mainPage = MainScreen()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainPage, animated: true)
```

The pushViewController doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try implementing the perfomSegueWithIdentifier method? Once the user is authenticated, try calling this method.

Comment: @Abdullah In both the cases you are using the same controller MainScreen(). Make sure you use right screens.

Comment: Do you need a storyboard for this? Cuz I don't use storyboards

Comment: @PavanKotesh I am using the correct controller, it's just that if the user is already logged in the first controller would be the main screen if not the login screen and once the user logs in the main screen will be displayed

Comment: This post could be helpful- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753925/set-initial-viewcontroller-in-appdelegate-swift

Comment: Check if navigation controller is not nil.

Comment: MainScreen() its a function or just an instance from your Viewcontroller  ?

Comment: Did you change main interface to nil from project target deployment info?

Comment: Thanks all for trying to help me, but I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that before you push a viewcontroller your root view controller must be a navigation view controller otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers but I figured it out.

```
// User found and verified, go to main page
let mainPage = MainScreen()
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainPage)
self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: the answer is totally different from what you asked in the question. In the question you are pushing a MainScreen view controller on the current navigation controller and the answer suggests presenting it.