# Swift 5. Objective: make the app open a specific View Controller without using segues

Tags: xcode, swift5

This code is in the AppDelegate.
Xcode doesn't throw any errors, but this code doesn't work when I recall the func in other View Controller buttons. ( Either make the app open on View Controller VC1 or VC2 )
The recall code:
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).configureInitialViewController()

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        configureInitialViewController()
        return true
    }

    **// determins which VC will be initially launched.**
    func configureInitialViewController() {
        var initialVC: UIViewController
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if 1 > 0 {
            initialVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: VC1)
        } else {
            initialVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: VC2)
        }
        window?.rootViewController = initialVC
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
```

Comment: In iOS 13 Xcode 11 the window belongs to the scene delegate, not the app delegate.

Comment: refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753925/set-initial-viewcontroller-in-appdelegate-swift

Answer (score 0):

Used your advice matt. ( SceneDelegate.swift file )
This is the code:

```
var window: UIWindow?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        if 1 > 0 {
            window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "INPUT YOUR STORYBOARD ID HERE")
        } else {
            window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "INPUT YOUR STORYBOARD ID HERE")
        }
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


}
```