# Swift: Two View Controllers presented

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Apologies for the ambiguity of the question; I'll try to explain clearer here.

## The Problem

I have some code in `AppDelegate.swift` that performs conditional navigation; if the user is signed in (and therefore `currentUser` is not `nil`), the app will start in `View`, a View Controller in the `Main` storyboard. Else, if the user isn't signed in, the app will start in `Welcome`, a View Controller in an `Auth` storyboard.

The following is my code from `AppDelegate.swift`, `ViewController.swift` (which is `View`), and `WelcomeViewController`.

> Note:
>
> `View` is the Storyboard ID I set for `ViewController`; `Welcome` is the Storyboard ID I set for `WelcomeViewController`.

`AppDelegate.swift`

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Configures the Firebase library.
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        // Performs conditional navigation on the condition of currentUser's status.
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        if user != nil {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "View")
            window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        } else {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Auth", bundle: nil)
            let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Welcome")
            window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        }

        return true
    }

}
```

`ViewController.swift`

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print("ViewController presented.")
    }

}
```

`WelcomeViewController.swift`

```swift
import UIKit

class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print("WelcomeViewController presented.")
    }

}
```

## Expectations

The app is freshly installed on the Simulator, and therefore there should be no `currentUser` (and upon debugging, proves to be true). Therefore, I'd expect to see this as the output in the Console:

```
WelcomeViewController presented.
```

Instead, this shows up in the Console:

```
WelcomeViewController presented.
ViewController presented.
```

## Attempts

So far, I thought that the problem might have arised from the fact that `Main` storyboard is the default Storyboard set since the creation of the project. Therefore, I tried unchecking the 'Initial View Controller' checkbox for the two View Controllers. Just like I'd expected, the following appears instead:

```
WelcomeViewController presented.
2020-06-20 11:39:38.724658+0800 AppName[11439:237509] [WindowScene] Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?
```

What should I do to make sure that `ViewController` doesn't appear and replace `WelcomeViewController`? All help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Solution

I managed to find the solution to the issue that I'm facing here. There are two mistakes above in the code, and I'll explain it here:

#### Mistake 1: Code should be in `SceneDelegate` instead of `AppDelegate` (iOS 13)

Xcode 11, along with the release of iOS 13, introduced `SceneDelegate.swift`. I was supposed to put my code above in `SceneDelegate.swift` instead of `AppDelegate.swift`; because I didn't do this, the code hadn't worked as I'd hoped for my Simulator, which was running iOS 13.5.

Here's my rectified code in `SceneDelegate.swift`:

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

        // Performs conditional navigation on the condition of currentUser's status.
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        if user != nil {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "View")
            window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        } else {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Auth", bundle: nil)
            let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Welcome")
            window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

#### Mistake 2 (Important!): Definition of new `UIWindow`

In my code above, there was a faulty line which caused the creation of a new `UIWindow`:

```swift
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

By removing this line of code, the problem was resolved. Here's the rectified code:

```swift
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
if user != nil {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "View")
    window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
} else {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Auth", bundle: nil)
    let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Welcome")
    window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

I hope this helps anyone else facing this issue!

Answer (score 1):

why not set WelcomeViewController as your 'Initial View Controller' and replace its viewDidLoad code with AppDelegate file then:

```
class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print("WelcomeViewController presented.")

        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        if user != nil {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "View")
            window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        } 
    }

}
```

you can also look this if you want to set the view controller from AppDelegate:

EDIT: 
you can use a UINavigationController as your initial view controller as indicated in this answer:

> [set initial viewcontroller in appdelegate - swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753925/set-initial-viewcontroller-in-appdelegate-swift) 
>   then you just need to set the correct view controller here:

```
navigationController.viewControllers = [rootViewController]
self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
```

Comment: That could work too, but I've read that you can do it directly from `AppDelegate` itself; I had planned that `WelcomeViewController` will be used for onboarding purposes and such. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: okay, see my edit, you can create a UINavigationController in your storyboard and set it as the initial view controller.