# Entrypoint is not changing

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I'm pretty new to Swift and Xcode and I can't find an answer online, so I hope you guys can help me.

I'm trying to change the screen when someone is logged in. I'm trying to change the default entry point to the other screen, but somehow it does not work.

This is in the `AppDelegate` where I am trying to change the entry point:

```swift
var window: UIWindow?
    
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main" , bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homePage") as! HomePageController
    window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Here I have set the ID for the screen/controller I want to replace with the default entry point (the default entry point is my login screen).

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [set initial viewcontroller in appdelegate - swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753925/set-initial-viewcontroller-in-appdelegate-swift)

Comment: @stackich I've tried that already, but my loginpage is still the entryset. My page does not change to the homepage

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you mean by `entry point`, where your VC is created and if you use storyboards (and specifically one storyboard for both VCs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it in sceneDelegate like that:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowsScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowsScene)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homePage") as! HomePageController
    window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
}
```