# Update which View Controller is called on launch

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller

I am updating an app that was initially built with a single view controller. That view controller is now only called when the user presses the Add button in the nav bar on either screen of the tab bar controller. I have updated the tab bar controller to be the initial view controller per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840449/xcode-how-to-change-which-viewcontroller-loads-first-at-start-up), however removing the "is initial view controller" from the original view controller is causing the build to fail. I am receiving the following error:

```
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
: error: TabBarStoryboard.storyboard references the initial view controller of Main.storyboard, but no designated entry point was found.
```

How can I tell Xcode that the tab bar view controller is the view controller to load when the app launches? [Here](https://github.com/andrewTuzson/MemeMe-2.0) is a link to the repo.

Comment: i download your repo. its work fine. When i run the code. Simulator directly show me Tab bar.

Comment: @andrew-tuzson : Repo you provided does not have TabBarStoryboard.storyboard clearly you missed to add it to repo. Anyhow if you have multiple storyboard go and update your target's main interface as shown in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select TabBarStoryboard as your Main interface in project settings as shown below

[image]

Select `TabBarStoryboard` from drop down in your project setting

Hope that helps

Comment: That did the trick. I wasn't even aware of that option. Thank you.

Comment: @andrew-tuzson : Am glad that it worked :) Happy coding :) Feel free to accept the answer :)